# Find child of div with particular text

Tags: jquery, css

I have a box, a div, and inside there are three children, displayed as three different words...

```
---------
|  Red
|  Green
|  Blue
--------
```

Anyways, I want change the text of `Red` to the color red. However, I do not know how to access this particular child. I tried...

```
$("#target :contains("Red")").children().css("color", "red");
```

However this changes all of them to red. I am clearly not using `contains` properly.

Comment: can u post html part also?

Comment: I actually cannot. This is a practice problem I found online and I am not actually supposed to know what the html is. The link of the site is here...http://jqexercise.droppages.com/    (so people dont think its hw)

Comment: that must be a different tag for each colour..so that effect will apply on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try css pseudo elements

```
#target > div:nth-child(1){color:red}
#target > div:nth-child(2){color:green}
#target > div:nth-child(3){color:blue}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4grsw7pq/)**

**jQuery solution**

```
$( "#target div:contains('Red')" ).css( "color", "red" );
```

You need to refer the child div which contains the specific text.

**[DEMO Jquery](https://jsfiddle.net/4grsw7pq/3/)**

Comment: He wants to do the color change based on the text inside, not based on the element position.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna do that using jQuery... then you have to split the words and replace it with some html code... I tried to do that... Kindly check the following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4865dwxf/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="target" style=" width: 155px; height: 150px; float: left; border: 1px solid rgb(119, 119, 119); margin: 10px; padding: 5px; background: rgb(204, 204, 204);">#target
  <br>
  <br>
  <span>
    red
    <br>
    blue
    <br>
    green
  </span>
</div>

<br>
<button class="change">
  Change
</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.change').on('click', function() {
    var str = $('#target span').html();
    console.log(str);
    var words = str.split("<br>");
    var clr = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
    var n = '';
    console.log(words);
    for (var i = 0; i <= words.length - 1; i++) {
      words[i] += " ";
      var m = words[i].replace(clr[i], '<br><span style=\'color:' + clr[i] + '\'>' + clr[i] + '</span>')
      n += m;

    }

    $('#target').children().remove();
    $('#target').append('<br>' + n);
  });
});
```

Comment: to use in that practice site copy paste the following code... it works 

**JQUERY**

~$(document).ready(function() {

 
    var str = $('#target span').html();

    console.log(str);

    var words = str.split("<br>");

    var clr = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

    var n = '';

    console.log(words);

    for (var i = 0; i <= words.length - 1; i++) {

      words[i] += " ";

      var m = words[i].replace(clr[i], '<br><span style=\'color:' + clr[i] + '\'>' + clr[i] + '</span>');

      n += m;

    }

    $('#target').children().remove();

    $('#target').append('<br>' + n);

  
});
~

Answer (score 1):

This changes the color of the divs that contain the colors.  I can't see what you did with your html so I can't tell you what's up with your code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>Red</div>
  <div>Green</div>
  <div>Blue</div>
</div>

<script>
  $('div:contains("Red")').css('color', 'red');
  $('div:contains("Green")').css('color', 'green');
  $('div:contains("Blue")').css('color', 'blue');
</script>
```

Comment: No you haven't because it works fine. See this fiddle. http://jsbin.com/yiridaqani/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @BikasVaibhav Well here is where I tested it http://jqexercise.droppages.com/#page_0023_    There is a solution provided but I wanted to figure out how to do it without replacing the html

Comment: Because the question is entirely different than what you've asked. It's a single span with `<br/>` tag. So since it contains red/blue/green all, it takes first and apply

Comment: @BikasVaibhav and theres no way of doing it without replacing the html? Like perhaps using filter to filter out a particular one?

Comment: you've to wrap each word with some tag. Look for it. And if you need help, let me know, I'll create the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

**1)** I guess the main problem with your code is that you do not use the quotations properly. Look at the following piece of your code:

```
$("#target :contains("Red")")
```

It is not possible to nest a string with quotation marks inside of another string surrounded by quotation marks. You should either use apostrophes are escape the quotation marks.

```
$("#target :contains('Red')")
```

**2)** The second thing to consider is the space between `#target` and `:contains`. If your HTML looks similar to this:

```
<div id="target">
    Red
    <span>This text will be read.</span>
    <span>This text will be read.</span>
</div>
```

then there should be no space in the selector, i.e. the JS code should be:

```
$("#target:contains('Red')").children().css("color", "red");
```

But if your HTML is similar to this one (notice the extra div):

```
<div id="target">
    <div>
      Red
      <span>This text will be read.</span>
      <span>This text will be read.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

then it is fine to have the space in the selector, i.e.:

```
$("#target :contains('Red')").children().css("color", "red");
```